# Can the Vāhanas (other than Garuda and Shesha) talk?

Tags: vahana

Can the Vāhanas, the animal/animal-like rides, talk?

Comment: Do you expect them to chit-chat like you and me? Editing the post and removing second question in the body section will retract my close vote.

Comment: I think only those two can talk.

Comment: What about Nandi? His conversations are found at many places.. bdw whose vahna is Shesha?

Comment: @YDS Nandi isn’t the Vahana. He’s like the chief of the ganas (Notwithstanding Ganeshji). The Vahana’s name is Chandraprabha.